# Compare between two char arrays with different lengths?

Tags: c, string, string-comparison

Is there a way to compare two char arrays with different length?

```
char_1[10] = "hello";
char_2[256] = "hello";

ret = strcmp(char_1,char_2); 
printf("%d\n", ret);
```

I don't get 0

I'm allowed to use any library I want...

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with `strcmp`?

Comment: "doesn't do the job" - What exactly is the "job"?

Comment: provide complete example, with expected output. do you really have a dot there? note: it's allowed, not aloud.

Comment: the command is 
ret = strcmp(char_1,char_2);
when I print the value of ret, I dont get 0

Comment: I just love how people ignore the comments..... does that look a complete example to you? what's the job? do you really have a dot there?

Comment: so you tell us what you *don't* get. great.

Answer (score 3):

You have to learn:

- How to describe what you want to do.
- How to provide complete example.

So, you haven't provided a proper example. It doesn't compile. It's full of syntactic errors. Here's a good example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char char_1[10] = "hello";
    char char_2[256] = "hello";

    int ret = strcmp(char_1,char_2);
    printf("%d\n", ret);
}
```

Which outputs `0`, as expected.

We don't know what your real code is, so we cannot know what your problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I need to read from a buffer some word (server side) and compare it with another word. the buffer size is 256, when I use the strcmp, I dont get 0 and according to this command, the two words (strings) are not equal.

Comment: I feel sorry for you. You cannot even interpret a simple sentence like "provide a complete example".

Answer (score 1):

Following is the declaration for `strcmp()` function.

`int strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)`

Parameters:

```
str1 -- This is the first string to be compared.

str2 -- This is the second string to be compared.
```

Return Value:

This function returned values are as follows:

```
if Return value if < 0 then it indicates str1 is less than str2

if Return value if > 0 then it indicates str2 is less than str1

if Return value if = 0 then it indicates str1 is equal to str2

strcmp(char_1,char_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct. strcmp returns zero. Just check it out.

```
char_1[10]="hello"
char_2[256]="hello"

ret= strcmp (char_1,char_2); 
printf("%d\n",ret);
```